# How to programmatically fetch list of youtube videos shared with a user using an API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-apps

If a user share some videos with all other or a group of users from our Google Apps domain, is there an API that allows me to fetch these videos, through authentication by any of our domain user. We want to fetch this list, even if user has not commented / liked these videos yet.

Comment: Did you see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: Yes Bruyere, I did check it in detail. It only gives me videos from my subscribed channels, my channels & recommended videos.